# Using Nodemailer, how to send email message using an alias gmail account? or a group google suite server account?

Tags: node.js, email, express, gmail, nodemailer

Using Nodemailer, how to send email message using an alias gmail account? or a group google suite server account?

Like for example:

My real account : `myaccount@domain.com`

I will send a message via my alias account or group account using nodemailer.

My alias account : `myaliasaccount@domain.com`

My group account : `mygroupaccount@domain.com`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure the alias in your gmail account. Check this link to configure https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en